# Сохранение ID в переменную, и поиск по нем

Tags: sql, postgresql, полнотекстовый-поиск

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой создаю функцию которая принимает ФИО дальше с помощью этого запроса я вывожу ID и результат совпадения с введенным ФИО

```
SELECT ID, maindb.TrigramFullName(employeesuniversity) <-> FullNames AS dist INTO IDSearch
FROM maindb.employeesuniversity
ORDER BY dist ASC;
```

Я хочу чтобы ID которое я получаю записывалось в отдельную переменную и потом использовать эти ID в другом запросе, вот то что у меня сейчас получилось,выводится только одно значение но я знаю что их там больше, как это можно исправить чтобы выводились все значения?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maindb.SearchFullName(FullNames VARCHAR)
  RETURNS TABLE (IDEmployees INT, FName VARCHAR, SName VARCHAR, Patronymic VARCHAR, DateBirth DATE, MobilePhone maindb.domainmobilephonenumber, CityPhone maindb.domaincityphonenumber, Dept VARCHAR, Pkod VARCHAR) AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
    IDSearch INT;
BEGIN 

SELECT ID, maindb.TrigramFullName(employeesuniversity) <-> FullNames AS dist INTO IDSearch
FROM maindb.employeesuniversity
ORDER BY dist ASC;

 RETURN QUERY 
 SELECT  e.ID, (FullName).FirstName, (FullName).SecondName, (FullName).Patronymic,e.DateOfBirth, e.MobilePhoneNumber, e.CityPhoneNumber, 
 coalesce(ss.DeptName,s.DeptName) AS Dept,case when ss.DeptName is null then null else s.DeptName end AS Pkod
 FROM maindb.EmployeesUniversity AS e
 INNER JOIN maindb.ListPositionSubdivision AS ls
 ON e.ID = ls.IDEmployees
 INNER JOIN maindb.StructuralSubdivision AS s
 ON ls.NameSubdivision = s.DeptKod
 LEFT JOIN maindb.StructuralSubdivision AS ss
 ON ss.DeptKod = s.PKod
 WHERE ls.EndDatePosition IS NULL AND e.ID = IDSearch;

END ;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION maindb.SearchFullName(FullNames VARCHAR)
  OWNER TO admin;
```

Comment: Но у вас первый запрос возвращает вообще все записи которые есть в employeesuniversity. Так что если вы используете все id rкоторые вернет тот запрос то получите то же самое как будто вы вообще условия по e.ID не задавали. И кстати не ясно, зачем вообще нужна переменная и отдельный запрос. Можно просто сделать первый запрос в виде подзапроса второго, в виде join или IN (убрав из него вызов функции и сортировку, потому что они не будут нести никакого смысла)

Comment: А можно пожалуйста реализацию?

Comment: реализацию чего ? замены `e.ID = IDSearch` на `e.ID IN(select ID from maindb.employeesuniversity)` ?

Comment: Мне нужно что в подзапросе было следующее WHERE ls.EndDatePosition IS NULL AND e.ID IN 
 (
  SELECT ID, maindb.TrigramFullName(employeesuniversity) <-> FullNames AS dist
  FROM maindb.employeesuniversity
  ORDER BY dist ASC
  ); но выводится ОШИБКА:  в подзапросе слишком много столбцов

Comment: И чтобы e.ID = ID того что вернет под запрос

Comment: выполните отдельно тот подзапрос и посмотрите что он возвращает, он возвращает _ВСЕ_ строки таблицы с дополнительной колонкой dist. А вы его должны переписать так, что бы он возвращал только нужные строки. А в подзапросе вы конечно не можете выбрать поле dist и оно там совершенно не нужно, ведь вам нужны только id которые он вернет. (а вот то сравнение <-> скорее всего можно писать в where или в order by, смотря что требуется)\